# How do I display the correct UI when it is waiting for a network request and the activity is paused?

Tags: android

I have an that requires the user to input a pin code which then does a network request to authenticate their login. If during this authentication the user clicks the "Recent Applications"/"Overview" button, waits for  some amount of time, and returns to the application, then the UI is not update although the request does complete.

I believe that the issue occurs in onPause(), it seems like by pausing the activity the current screen is saved and when it is resumed this screen is shown instead of having the next screen displayed.

Is there any way to update the after the authentication or when I resume? I appreciate any help, thanks!

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Utils.currentActivity = this;

    boolean wakingUp = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(Utils.MY_EXTRA_WAKING_UP, false);
    if (wakingUp) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    }

    My_Screen screen = getScreen();
    if(screen != null)
        screen.onDisplay();         // performs some user defined 
                                    // function, currently does 
                                    // nothing .

    String notificationId = getIntent().getStringExtra(Utils.MY_EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_ID);
    if (notificationId != null) {
        getIntent().removeExtra(Utils.MY_EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_ID);
        Utils.callMethod(Utils.NOTIFICATIONS_SERVICE, "dispatchNotificationTriggeredEvent", notificationId);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Utils.callMethod(Utils.APPLICATION_SERVICE, "onActivityPaused", this);

    My_Screen screen = getScreen();
    if (screen != null)
        screen.onHide();            // Performs user defined function
                                    // currently does nothing.
}
```

Comment: I read that as in place some check in onResume. Can you please elaborate on what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the network request is completed, set a sharedPreference to indicate that it is completed. eg:

```
getSharedPreferences(
      "mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("completed",true).apply();
```

and in onResume check if this preference is true. If it is true, then update the UI accordingly.